# Check whether two comma separated strings are equal (for Content set)

Tags: c#, linq

I have four string as listed below. Though they have different order of characters and different spacing after comma – they are considered to have `same business value`.

1. How do I check that all the strings are same (according to the business scenario explained above) ?  I have following code but it fails in the case of space after comma.
2. What is the better method (for this purpose) than `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`?

Note: "A,B" will be considered same as "B,A,B,A,B"

Note: I am using `Visual Studio 2010` with `.Net Framework 4`

**CODE**

```
  string firstString = "A,B,C";
  string secondString = "C,A,B";
  string thirdString = "A,B, C";
  string fourthString = "C, A,B";


  //Set 1 Test
  List<string> firstList = new List<string>(firstString.Split(','));
  List<string> secondLsit = new List<string>(secondString.Split(','));
  bool isStringsSame = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(firstList.OrderBy(t => t), secondLsit.OrderBy(t => t));
  Console.WriteLine(isStringsSame);


  //Set 2 Test
  List<string> thirdList = new List<string>(thirdString.Split(','));
  List<string> fourthList = new List<string>(fourthString.Split(','));
  bool isOtherStringsSame = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(thirdList.OrderBy(t => t), fourthList.OrderBy(t => t));
  Console.WriteLine(isOtherStringsSame);

  Console.ReadLine();
```

**UPDATE**:

Use `OrdianlIgnoreCase` for ignoring case sensitvity   [How to use HashSet<string>.Contains() method in case -insensitive mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667635/how-to-use-hashsetstring-contains-method-in-case-insensitive-mode)

**REFERENCE**:

1. [Best way to check for string in comma-delimited list with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586602/best-way-to-check-for-string-in-comma-delimited-list-with-net)
2. [Compare two List<T> objects for equality, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order)
3. [Why does the IEnumerable<T>.Select() works in 1 of 2 cases ? Can not be inferred from usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629650/why-does-the-ienumerablet-select-works-in-1-of-2-cases-can-not-be-inferred)
4. [What is the shortest code to compare two comma-separated strings for a match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124216/what-is-the-shortest-code-to-compare-two-comma-separated-strings-for-a-match)
5. [Split a separated string into hierarchy using c# and linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060354/split-a-separated-string-into-hierachy-using-c-sharp-and-linq?rq=1)
6. [Count matching characters between two strings using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285347/count-matching-characters-between-two-strings-using-linq?rq=1)
7. [Usinq Linq to select items that is in a semi-comma separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536925/usinq-linq-to-select-items-that-is-in-a-semi-comma-separated-string?rq=1)
8. [Determine whether two or more objects in a list are equal according to some property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162545/determine-whether-two-or-more-objects-in-a-list-are-equal-according-to-some-prop?rq=1)

Comment: Would you consider A,B to be equal to B,A,B,A,B? If so, you should be using sets. If not, an ordered sequence is appropriate.

Comment: @JonSkeet "A,B" will be considered same as "B,A,B,A,B"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would you consider A,B to be equal to B,A,B,A,B? If so, you should be using sets. If not, an ordered sequence is appropriate.

EDIT: Now we know you actually want set equality:

```
var set1 = new HashSet<string>(firstString.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
bool setsEqual = set1.SetEquals(secondString.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
```

---

If we *weren't* after set equality...

To ignore the spaces, you should just trim them. For example:

```
var firstOrdered = firstString.Split(',')
                              .Select(t => t.Trim())
                              .OrderBy(t => t);
var secondOrdered = secondString.Split(',')
                                .Select(t => t.Trim())
                                .OrderBy(t => t); 
bool stringsAreEqual = firstOrdered.SequenceEqual(secondOrdered);
```

Comment: "A,B" will be considered same as "B,A,B,A,B"

Comment: it would have saved me answering late again. +1

Comment: When I use the set code, I get following error - Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Lijo: Which version of C# are you using? I'd expect that to work with C# 4, but there's an easy fix - I'll edit it now.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .Net Framework 4

Comment: @Lijo: Okay - looks like the fact that `Trim` is overloaded could have been the problem here. See if my edit fixes it though.